# join on timestamp range

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

```
raw_commits(sha,date,author)
```

and

```
milestones(name,start,end)
```

where the `milestones` table contains the timestamp range for all the project's milestones.

I am unsure on how to go about the `JOIN` to achieve the following:

For each `raw_commits`, show the `raw_commits.sha, raw_commits.date, raw_commits.author, milestones.name` if it has one milestone, show `NULL` if it doesn't "belong" to a milestone, and show duplicate rows for each milestone, if the commit "belongs" to multiple `milestones`.

The categorization into `milestones` is obviously done by using the `raw_commits.date` as a reference, i.e. `raw_commits.date >= milestones.start AND raw_commits.date <= milestones.end`.

How to achieve the described behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  raw_commits.sha,
  raw_commits.author
  raw_commits.date,
  milestones.name
FROM
  raw_commits
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  milestones
ON
  raw_commits.date BETWEEN milestones.start AND milestones.end
```